# How follow meta redirect with curl and php?

Tags: php, curl

```
$url='http://wtion';
$headers = array(
    'GET '.$url.' HTTP/1.1',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3',
  'Accept: text/html',
  'Accept-Language: ru,en-us;',
 'Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;',
    'Connection: close');

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);//Массив с HTTP заголовками для передачи на сервер
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   //Не выводить ответ в браузер. Пусть функция пишет все в переменную. 
$site=curl_exec($ch);                          //В случае успеха - html тест запрошенной страницы. Иначе - false                         
curl_close($ch);

echo $site;
```

After running the code , I get this line

```
<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; url=/animation.php'>
```

How can I follow the redirect and get the response of `/animation.php`?

Comment: You can try to parse the html first to match `refresh "/something.php"` and then curl `something.php`

Comment: Doesn't the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATIONS do this? Just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an implementation in a comment of [get_meta_tags()](http://php.net/manual/it/function.get-meta-tags.php#117176) documentation page.

```
function sendRequest($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    /*curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'GET '.$url.' HTTP/1.1', // Are you sure about this?
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3',
        'Accept: text/html',
        'Accept-Language: ru,en-us;',
        'Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;',
        'Connection: close'
    ));*/

    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $contents;
}

function getUrlContents($url, $maximumRedirections = null, $currentRedirection = 0)
{
    $result = false;

    $contents = sendRequest($url);

    // Check if we need to go somewhere else

    if (isset($contents) && is_string($contents))
    {
        preg_match_all('/<[\s]*meta[\s]*http-equiv="?REFRESH"?' . '[\s]*content="?[0-9]*;[\s]*URL[\s]*=[\s]*([^>"]*)"?' . '[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si', $contents, $match);

        if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) == 2 && count($match[1]) == 1)
        {
            if (!isset($maximumRedirections) || $currentRedirection < $maximumRedirections)
            {
                return getUrlContents($match[1][0], $maximumRedirections, ++$currentRedirection);
            }

            $result = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $result = $contents;
        }
    }

    return $contents;
}

echo getUrlContents('http://wtion');
```

Answer (score 1):

Curl cannot follow a meta refresh.  Use DOMXml to parse the curl response as long as it's valid, you can check for a refresh return, then process the refresh path appropriately.

```
$url='http://wtion';
$headers = array(
    'GET '.$url.' HTTP/1.1',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3',
  'Accept: text/html',
  'Accept-Language: ru,en-us;',
 'Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;',
    'Connection: close');

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);//Массив с HTTP заголовками для передачи на сервер
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   //Не выводить ответ в браузер. Пусть функция пишет все в переменную. 
$site=curl_exec($ch);                          //В случае успеха - html тест запрошенной страницы. Иначе - false                         
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_file($site);
$result = $xml->xpath("//meta[@http-equiv='refresh']");

if (!empty($result)) {
    ... do stuff to get the final $site value....
}

echo $site
```