# Unable to download file with cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to download a file from this URL in PHP with cURL.

https://www.geopoi.it/geopoiAPI/php/utils/omixml/getOMIXML.php?&t=p&f=KML&id=61932577_ras

I resolve the captcha of the form im PHP, I manage the cookies, etc, and then, when i'm going to download nothing happens. This is the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 25 Oct 2018 09:36:51 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.15
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

**This is my code:**

```
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.geopoi.it/geopoiAPI/php/utils/omixml/getOMIXML.php?&cf=RTRRTR89T55F205K&p1=5&p2=2&p3=5&cod='.$captcha.'&ok=2&t=p&f=KML&id=553423949_ras');
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);       
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'any');
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);   
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , [
             'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
             'Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.7,gl;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,de;q=0.4',
             'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36',
             'Cookie: '. self::COOKIE_NAME . '=' . $cookie,
             'Connection: keep-alive',
             'Host: www.geopoi.it',
             'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1']);
```

I don't understand because it works in my navigator but with cURL the call  doesn't work.

Any idea??

Many thanks!

Comment: how did you set the `$captcha` variable? (it's not explained in above code)

Comment: I set it with an OCR (I get the image with cURL and then I apply the OCR).

Comment: where is your `curl_exec()` call ?

Comment: It's in the end. I put only the main part of the curl sentences.

Comment: it would be great if you show where you store the returned value of `curl_exec` and how you check it and what you mean by "nothing happens", i.e. your expected results

Comment: Where I except its to download a file so in my navigator, when i access to that URL these are the headers when I download the file:

`Cache-Control: must-revalidate`
`Connection: close`
`Content-Disposition: attachment; `filename=Provincia%20di%20LUCCA%202018-1.kmz`
`Content-Encoding: gzip`
`Content-Type: application/vnd.google-earth.kmz`
`Date: Thu, 25 Oct 2018 09:46:58 GMT`
`Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT`
`Pragma: no-cache`
`Server: Apache`
`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

But in my cURL call I don't receive any data and the response header is the one that I wrote before.

Comment: And this is what I store the value:

$response = curl_exec($curl);

The response is:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

`Date: Thu, 25 Oct 2018 10:44:41 GMT`

`Server: Apache`

`X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.15`

`Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT`

`Cache-Control: must-revalidate`

`Pragma: no-cache`

`Content-Length: 0`

`Connection: close`

`Content-Type: text/html`

Answer (score 0):

the core problem seems to be:
 your code doesn't seeem to handle refresh meta that the form is returning:

```
(...)
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=getOMIXML.php?&t=p&f=KML&id=61932577_ras&cf=TSTTST80A01L152H&p1=1&p2=1&p3=1&cod=tnChb29&ok=2" />
(...)
```

The above is in the form respone `<body>`.
This means AFTER you query the form with your CURL, you need to scrap the response for the refresh meta and query that url with same request data again.

There was another posting similiar to this problem here:
[How follow meta redirect with curl and php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939465/how-follow-meta-redirect-with-curl-and-php)
so feel free to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I have the URL to download the file that I want (the URL that appears in the "meta"), so when I make the cURL call I don't receive the file, I only receive a blank page.

Comment: the thing is, you cannot JUST curl the result page, you need to send it through form. this is because on the server it registes that THIS particular request is now granted with file download permissions.

Comment: janmyszkier, thanks a lot. Can you explain me a little more that response?? I have to do a POST call instead a GET? I'm totally desperate :(

Comment: yes, you need to do a post with that captcha code to form `action` URL and analyze the response body for refresh meta, then pick the actual url from that refresh meta, and go another request to it (same cookies, no data, ths time GET - for meta url - should be enough)

Comment: Thanks! I'm just doing that but it isn't working.

I get the URL from the "meta" (returned in the POST call), then i make a GET call to that URL to make the downloading but I only get and empty page :(